# How to free a tree struct using double pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, tree, double-pointer

I have to free a tree and set his root to NULL using a particular function. I tried to use a recoursive method. But if I compile i get some warnings about "incompatible pointer type" and I'm not able to resolve it. This is the struct:

```
typedef struct node {
int key; 
struct node *left, *mid, *right;
} node_t;
```

And here the function. The first line cannot be changed:

```
void free_tree (node_t ** root){
if(root != NULL){
    free_tree((*root)->left);
    free_tree((*root)->mid);
    free_tree((*root)->right);
    free(*root);
    }
return;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, when asking question about build errors or warnings, please include the *exact* messages you get, by copy-paste, as text, in full and complete. And mark out (with comments) where in the code you get the errors or warnings.

Comment: All of those pointers should be passed by address; you're passing them by value in your recursive calls. Ex: `free_tree((*root)->left)` should be `free_tree(&(*root)->left)`. Which makes me believe it  likely the initiating caller of `free_tree` with root is wrong as well, but we inconveniently were not blessed with that code. Lastly, you should check both `root` and `*root` before recursing.

Comment: Lastly a hint about your problem: What is the type of `(*root)->left`? What is the type expected by `free_tree`?

Comment: @SandeepKokate for sure, thanks.

Comment: @WhozCraig I tried before to use that type of format because i know that the function requires a double pointer and i was giving it a simple pointer. And the compilation was without any warning but if i tried to execute it, i received a segmentation fault message (core dump) from the terminal.

Comment: That isn't a type-of-format. That is *exactly* what that function requires. If the code faults it means you did *not* do the second thing I said (check `*root` before recursing). All of that assumes your tree is properly built and all leaves have three null pointers in their members.

Comment: You forgot to show the code that calls `free_tree` and you forgot to show us where exactly the errors occur.  Please read this: [ask] and this: [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function expected a pointer to a pointer-to-node. You're giving it a pointer-to-node three times in your recursive calls. Further, you're not validating that the pointer-to-pointer, *and* the pointer it points to, are non-null; you're only validating the former.

In short, your function should look like this:

```
void free_tree (node_t ** root)
{
    if(root && *root)
    {
        free_tree(&(*root)->left);
        free_tree(&(*root)->mid);
        free_tree(&(*root)->right);
        free(*root);
        *root = NULL;
    }
}
```

The last functional line is optional, but frankly it's pointless to do this with pointers-to-pointers unless you're going to do that anyway, as it sets the caller's pointer to NULL after obliterating the tree. Given a properly built tree, your caller should deliver the address of the tree root when destroying the entire tree, as:

```
node_t *root = NULL;

// ... build tree ...

free_tree(&root);

// root is now NULL; tree is destroyed
```

Comment: I think that I've understand the problem. I'll try to do the code on my own. But I'm really glad to you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your question cannot be answered very clearly but at least I can tell you why you have this warning about `incompatible pointer type` :

Your function prototype is

```
void free_tree (node_t ** root);
```

It's argument is a `node_t **`.

Your struct is

```
typedef struct node {
    int key; 
    struct node *left, *mid, *right;
} node_t;
```

So in your function :

```
void free_tree (node_t ** root)
{
    if(root != NULL)
    {
        free_tree((*root)->left);   <<< '(*root)->left' is of type 'node_t *'
        free_tree((*root)->mid);    <<< '(*root)->mid' is of type 'node_t *'
        free_tree((*root)->right);  <<< '(*root)->right' is of type 'node_t *'
        free(*root);
    }
    return;
}
```

You call you function giving a `node_t *` as argument whereas your function  expects a `node_t **`